# Examples of asymptotic formulas with optimal error term

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Many problems in analytic number theory regard the error term in asymptotic formulas. These problems usually take the form: prove that the number theoretic quantity $f(n)$ satisfies $f(n) = G(n) + O(n^{e})$ for some exponent $e$ where $G(n)$ is an elementary function. In many cases lower bounds on the permissible values of $e$ are known.

What are some examples of nontrivial number theoretic problems, particularly asymptotic formulas, where best possible error terms/exponents are known?

Comment: [This comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308691/motivated-account-of-the-prime-number-theorem-and-related-topics?rq=1#comment768578_308691) might be interesting, and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42900/) as well.

Answer (score 6):

If $r_k(n)$ is the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ squares, and $k\geq 5$, then the estimate

$\sum_{n \leq X}r_k(n)=C_k X^{\frac{k}{2}}+O(X^{\frac{k}{2}-1})$

is known, and is best possible, because $r_k(n) \neq o(n^{\frac{k}{2}-1})$.

Comment: Could you give me a reference for this?

Comment: Sure, it's in chapter one of Iwaniec and Kowalski's book on analytic number theory.

Answer (score 5):

It's a nice question. As you know the best orders of the error terms in most important asymptotic formulas are still unknown. (Riemann Hypothesis as the best error term in PNT, [Dirichlet's divisor problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem), [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) etc.)

A few examples of asymptotics that come to mind, that are useful and (some of them, kind of?) sharp include:

- The [Sato-Tate conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sato%E2%80%93Tate_conjecture), which is proven in many cases
- The theorem of [Bombieri-Vinogradov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri-Vinogradov%27s_theorem), concerning the error term in the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions, is a very strong result and unconditional replacement of the error predicted by GRH. However this is not optimal as you can see from the Elliott-Halberstam conjecture.
- [The fundamental lemma of sieve theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_sieve_theory).
- Results like: Denote the number of prime factors of $n$ counting multiplicity by $\Omega(n)$, then $$\# \{n\le x |\Omega(n)\equiv j\mod m \}=\frac{x}{m}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^k x}\right)$$ for some $k>0$, and the error term is not $o(x^k)$ for any $1>k$.

  The divisor bound $d(n)\le \exp((1+\epsilon)\log 2 \log n/\log \log n)$, which holds for any $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $n$, but is false for any negative $\epsilon$,

  [Smoothing sums](http://www.tricki.org/article/Smoothing_sums)! from the Tricki. This is not a sharp estimate but more of a technique of how to find one.(and I really like the article)

Comment: Which one is of the form $G(n)+O(G_1(n))$ with $G_1(n)=o(G(n))$ and sharp?

Comment: There are some examples of sharp estimates for counting lattice points in certain domains, but here an expertise of somebody from analytic number theory is required.

Comment: Sato-Tate is definitely of that form :) and so is Bombieri-Vinogradov(but is not _sharpest_ )

Comment: I agree with your second comment, of course.

Comment: Bombieri--Vinogradov is not sharp, but the proven cases of Sato--Tate are indeed sharp (but not on the side of analytic number theory). In any case, Mark Lewko might be satisfied by your answer. I simply vote...

Comment: Note: Sato--Tate is now proved in general (even for elliptic curves over totally real fields).

Comment: I think you lifted your result about the number of prime factors of an integer from a certain paper on the arXiv. I would like to point out that sharper results (than included in that paper) follow easily from the Selberg-Delange method: indeed you can get an asymptotic expansion for the number of integers n <= x with Omega(n) = k (mod l). For l > 2 the asymptotic expansion takes the form x/l + c_1*x/(log x) + c_2*x/(log x)^2 + ... with constant c_i. When l = 2 all the c_i's vanish and the error term is expected to be O(x^{1/2+epsilon}), which is in fact equivalent to RH. 

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ denote the Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Then, uniformly in $t$, the number of integers $n \leq x$ with $\omega(n) \leq \log\log n + t \sqrt{\log\log n}$ is $$\Phi(t) + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log\log x}}\right)$$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  **The error term is sharp.**

This particular error term was conjectured to hold by Leveque in the 40's. His conjecture was settled a few years later by Erdos and Renyi.

Before Erdos and Renyi's paper the best error term was $O(\log\log\log x / \sqrt{\log\log x})$ and was due (if I recall correctly) to Kubilius. Kubilius's method was in its origin probabilistic and relied in an essential way on truncating the "random variable" $\omega(n)$. This introduced an additional factor of $\log\log\log x$ to the error term, as inevitably, truncation leads to loss of information.

In contrast, Renyi's and Erdos's method was purely analytic: the idea was to estimate $\sum_{n \leq x} exp(\text{i}t \omega(n))$ uniformly in $t$ in a certain range, and extract the desired conclusion from the behavior of this sum. To this end, they apply Berry-Esseen's theorem, but in principle one could use an more hands-on approach: smooth the indicator function of $\omega(n) \leq \log\log n + t \sqrt{\log\log n}$ and express it in terms of a variant of Perron's formula, after summing the resulting expression over $n \leq x$ one could proceed with the saddle-point method.

However when purely analytic methods are not directly accessible, Kubilius's method is the canonical method. For example suppose that you want to investigate the distribution of $\omega(n)$ over a peculiar subset of $[1,x]$ on which sieve methods -- but not "heavy" analytic methods -- are applicable, then Kubilius's method is still your best bet.

(As far as terminology is concerned it's "Kubilius model's" rather than "Kubilius's method"; more details about "Kubilius's model" can be found in Volume 1 of Elliott's "Probabilistic Number Theory").

Answer (score 2):

Let $0\le a<b$ and $l(a/b)$ be the length of continued fraction expansion $a/b=[0;q_1,\ldots,a_l]$. Then (see [Asymptotic behaviour of the first and second moments for the number of steps in the Euclidean algorithm](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth19_eng.pdf))
$$\frac{2}{R(R+1)}\sum_{0\le a\le b\le R}l(a/b)=\frac{2\log2}{\zeta(2)}\log R+C+O(R^{-1}\log ^5R).$$

According to numerical experiments this error term is best possible up to some power of $\log R$. (Optimality is not proved so far.)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not what you were thinking of, but very precise versions of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to the factorial are known.