# What would Cramer's conjecture teach us about the zeroes of Zeta?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

I have just read this: [Refinements of the Riemann hypothesis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42900/refinements-of-the-riemann-hypothesis) and I came up with the following question: what would Cramer's conjecture, if proven, teach us about the zeroes of Zeta? For example, does this conjecture imply that all non trivial zeroes of Zeta are on the critical line and simple? Or can we expect even much more?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cramer's conjecture implies that the gaps between consecutive primes is $O(\sqrt x\log x)$ (and much better, of course) and so that the Riemann Hypothesis is true and so all nontrivial zeros are on the critical line. I don't know if it rules out nonsimple zeros.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if this were so. In part., I am quite convinced (but have no sufficiently good argument to give this as an answer) that it would be in principle possible that Cramér's conjecture is true but RH false. I am even more concinced regarding the simplicty of zero's, since I am unaware of any strong implications on the distribution of primes a simple zero would have. There might be things to be said that the zero's cannot too "extremly" deviate from what one expects, but a couple of exceptional zero's (off the line or double) should not necess. make prime dist that irreg.  

Comment: @Charles: I did not see your comment before writing mine. I am a bit unsure now. But how does the bound on gaps imply RH. 

Comment: RH implies the gap between consecutive primes is $O(\sqrt{x}\log^2{x})$, but the converse implication need not hold. Cramer's conjecture and the distribution of the zeros are basically unrelated.